# I want to convert created_datetime (Format -- 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS' ) to created_date (Format -- 'yyyy-MM-dd') in hive or presto sql query

Tags: sql, hive, presto, trino

there is a datetime column with the Format -- 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS'  and i want convert it into date column with the format -- 'yyyy-MM-dd'

[image: Error screen shot]

database source -- hive/presto

This is the current format `2023-02-28 22:10:19.629` but i want to convert it to `2023-02-28`

I have tried all of these i am not able convert to only date

```
-- from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(created_dt, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS'), 'yyyy-MM-dd') AS date_column
--                         cast(created_dt as date)
--                         format_datetime(created_dt,'YYYY-mm-dd')
--                        date(created_dt) as cdt
--                         to_date(str created_dt) as cdt
--                         from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('2023-02-28 22:10:19.629', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS'), 'yyyy-MM-dd') AS date
```

Comment: i found a way to convert it using substing and cast it to date

this might help other

**'cast(substr(created_dt,1,10) as date)'**

Comment: `cast(... as date)` in Presto can be substituted with `date(...)`.

Comment: Noooo. Thanks to cultural/internationalization issues, casting to string and back is -- _by far_ -- the slower and less-safe way to do this.

Comment: A datetime column has no format. It just contains the date/time information in some binary format. You want to get the date only. `cast(created_dt as date)` does this, as well as `date(created_dt)`. What happened when you tried these? If you want to get the date as a string in a particular format (e.g. yyyy-mm-dd), then use `format_datetime(created_dt,'yyyy-MM-dd')`. Notice upper/lower case here; you had minutes instead of the month.

Answer (score 1):

For Presto/Trino you can use [Java date functions](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#java-date-functions):

```sql
-- sample data
with dataset(dt) as (
    values ('2023-02-28 22:10:19.629')
)

-- query
select format_datetime(
        parse_datetime(dt, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS'),
        'yyyy-MM-dd')
from dataset;
```

Output:

```
   _col0    
------------
 2023-02-28
```

`parse_datetime` actually returns a `timestamp`, you can cast it to date if needed.